# How to get audio stream from html video element?

Tags: html, html5-video, audio-streaming, aws-chime-sdk

I have a `video` element in my HTML code. That `video` element plays a video (video is coming from AWS Chime SDK). I need to get the audio stream for the audio coming from that `video` element for analysis (eg. for generating transcriptions). Is it possible to get an audio stream from that video element? If yes, how?

Comment: How are you planning to perform this analysis? You can "play" only the audio by using an <audio> element, you can get a MediaStream with only the AudioTracks by doing `new MediaStream(<video>.captureStream().getAudioTracks())`, but for analysis what we generally do is to use the AudioContext API and its `decodeAudioData`, which is able to read the audio data from a video buffer just well.

Comment: For the analysis I need to send the audio stream to AWS Transcribe. Earlier I was using ffmpeg to get audio from an rtmp stream (like [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-auto-captions-web-demo/blob/main/serverless/transcribe-server/run.sh#L40)) and I was sending it to [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ivs-auto-captions-web-demo/blob/main/serverless/transcribe-server/src/transcribe.js#L47) node js script. But now I have input from an HTML video element instead of rtmp. How can I fetch this stream?